# Pressure in a swim ring

Tags: pressure

I have a work related question and would love a physicist’s perspective.
My problem essentially boils down to whether the pressure is greater on the inner or outer “welding” in a round swimming ring, when it is inflated. My intuition tells me that they are equal, but I can’t explain why. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The pressure is the same everywhere in the ring.

That does NOT mean that tensions, force, or stress are the same

Comment: Those two sentences deserve to be slightly expanded:  "...pressure _of the air inside_...the ring." and "...stress _within the PVC fabric._"

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is wrong.

If you assume the ring is a membrane (i.e. it if it was not inflated, the material it could not resist bending) the tension at any point depends (inversely) on the curvature of the membrane, which is different on the inside and the outside.

Unfortunately I can't find a simple reference to the mechanical behaviour on the web, since Google searches are mainly about the what happens to curved cell membranes in biology, and other relatively complicated applications of the theory.

Comment: I think the question was about pressure and not tension.